# How to pass url(include '&' operator) in query string without encode at direct address bar?

Tags: php, laravel, url, querystringparameter

I'm used laravel framework.

How to pass **url(include '&' operator)** in query string without encode at write **direct address bar**?

Like this: (**without encode**)

`https://test.com/test?q=test&url=http://ddd.com?dd=dd&aa=aa&cc=cc`

I want below like result query params in code

```
['q' => test, 'url' => 'http://ddd.com?dd=dd&aa=aa&cc=cc']
```

How can do i?

Comment: Is it a route? or just a specific Url?

Comment: yes it is a route url

Comment: I would highly encourage you *do* encode it - even if you get it to create a url back to your own route without encoding it, I don't know how well Laravel will handle it as a genuine route... Is there a reason *why* it shouldn't be encoded?

Comment: i should not encode it. Users who use that url do not know the concept of encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Since Laravel will try and remove `http://` from the string, you can try adding the url like this.

```
url('/my-url', [
  'q' => 'test',
]) . 'url?=http://..../';

// or

route('my.route.get', [
  'q' => 'test',
]) . 'url?=http://..../';
```

Comment: not working for me  real response result is ['q'=>'test', 'url'=>'http://ddd.com?dd=dd' , 'aa' =>'aa' , 'cc' => 'cc' ]

Comment: @KwanUngPark Please, check now. This is the best you can do, since laravel remove http:// from concurrent strings.

Comment: It is a method to input directly into the address bar without working on code. This way is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Say your route looks like this:

```
Route::get('/{id}, array('as' => 'test.route', function($id){
    return $id;
}));
```

You would generate a link like this in your view

```
<a href="{{ route('test.route', array('id' => 1,  'something' => 'here',  'another' => 'there')) }}">click here</a>
```

Your url would look like this:

```
http://localhost:8000/1?something=here&another=there
```

[more](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/generating-a-route-with-a-query-string-parameter)